# Trying to add quantity to my list<object>

Tags: c#, listbox

hi i have a program that is a Mediastore and i have 3 classes. 
Produkt: which is a class with a few variables that i use to add products to my List.

```
public class produkt
{


    public string Name;
    public string price;
    public string Serialnumber;
    public int kvantitet;

    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return "ProduktNamn: " + Name + 
               " VaruNr: (" + Serialnumber + ") " + 
               "Pris: " + price + 
               " Kr" + " Kvantitet " +kvantitet; 
    }
```

LagerList : This class is static and is only used to store my List so that it can be acessed from diffrent forms.

```
public static class LagerList
{
    public static List<produkt> List = new List<produkt>();
}
```

then i have my Lager class which i use to add my products to my list and Listbox.
This is done by having 3 textfields where i say what the Name,SerialNumber and Price of the object i created should have.

In this class i also have 2 more textfields and a button that is suposed to make it possible to add a quantity of the selected listbox object of my product Class. 
if the item im trying to add a quantity to dosent exist i get a question if i wanna add that product and it adds that product to the list.
if however the product allready exist its suposed to add the quantity with the selected amount from my textbox. 
This is how my AddQuantity method looks like right now.

```
private void TaBort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabort_();
}



private void LäggTillLev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string productname;

    productname = ProduktNr.Text;

    if (LagerList.List.Any(produkt => produkt.Name == productname))
    {
        // here i wanna add the quantity
    }
    else if (LagerList.List.Any(produkt => produkt.Name != productname))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Lägg till Ny vara?", "Titel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            var newProdukt = new produkt()
            {

                Name = productname,
                Serialnumber = " ",
                price = " ",
                kvantitet = "",

            };

            LagerList.List.Add(newProdukt);

            Lista.DataSource = LagerList.List;
            var Lager_vy = new Lager();
            Lager_vy.Show();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //do something else
        }

    }
        return;

    }
```

Some variables that can be good to know is My List from the class LagerList is called List.
My Listbox is called Lista. 
what i need help with is how i can add the quantity to that selected item i've tried many diffrent ways and looked for answers everywhere but have come up empty so thats why im asking here hope you can help.

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
    productname = ProduktNr.Text;
    var existingProduct =  LagerList.List.FirstOrDefault(produkt => produkt.Name == productname);

    if (existingProduct != null )
    {
        // here i wanna add the quantity
        existingProduct.kvantitet = int.Parse(ProduktKvantitet.Text);
    }
    else
    {
      // dialog code
    }
```

basically we try get the Product from the list. if we find the product, we set its quantity. if we don't find it, then you ask for the prompt and create a new product.

Comment: I would just change the int.Parse with Int32.TryParse